# How can I force set the distance between my divs?

Tags: html, css

I am not sure why my `margin:13.5px;` doesn't take any effect.
I want to set them aside from each other **27px**.
But now this is what I get :

[image]

Can someone help me give space between them ?

Here is what I have : [`JSFiddle`](https://jsfiddle.net/bheng/pvv2c6ew/)

Comment: Where have you added the margin in the jsfiddle?

Comment: @Pete : I add my margin in class `.tl-box`. Did you see my view fine ?

Comment: @dowomenfart : Do you still have a problem display my output ? It seems like other people have no problem seeing it. Please expand your output windows to see that.

Comment: I think your problem is that as `tl-box` is inside `col-lg-2` and seems to overflow it, the margin won't be shown.  [Ths fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pvv2c6ew/2/) shows you what I'm talking about - your `tl-box`es are cut off as they are too large for the containing div.  Sort that out and it will fix your issue

Comment: @Pete: It seems like you are answering my question. What did you do to fix it ? Do you suggest me take off `col-lg-2` completely ? What is it ?

Comment: Ah yes, Pete is right. Increase the width of the `.col-lg-2` divs to at least 240px.

Comment: !!? margin will collapse , so if you want your boxes away 27px from each other, set margin:27px;. **0.5pixel** will not do much, pixel cannot be broken into parts. https://jsfiddle.net/pvv2c6ew/5/

Comment: @GCyrillus : Your fiddle produce 404

Comment: @rangerover.js it was a fork of your original fiddle, itself producing a 404 page, i guess he deleted it here an update from ypurs https://jsfiddle.net/54urb9zb/7/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure your container div is the right size for your inner div - at the moment it is too small so your inner div isn't showing the margin.  If you remove the margin from `.tl-box` and then add the following styles (makes the outer box the correct width for it's contents and adds the margin to it), it should fix your issue:

```
.slide .col-lg-2 {
    width:239px;
    margin:13.5px; 
}
```

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/pvv2c6ew/4/)

Comment: Thank you Pete. You're a css expert. Hey man, while you at it, in your JSFiddle, can you please help me move my dash line to the back of those 3 divs, and center it. I tried it, but I couldn't push it to the back. I even tried setting the `z-index` and everything.

Comment: Sorry, was just called into a meeting. I think you've deleted the fiddle (if you remove the root fiddle - ie the one you created, then it will remove all the subsequent versions of that fiddle, whether you created them or other people created them)

Comment: Here is your [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bheng/54urb9zb/1/). I fork it before I deleted it. I didn't aware that this will affect others.

Comment: not sure what you are after with the blue line - something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/54urb9zb/5/ or this https://jsfiddle.net/54urb9zb/6/

Comment: You're very close, The last thing I want to do with them is place in the back of my divs, I tried set the `z-index` but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: could you do an imagur of what you want it to look like, will be easier as I don't quite understand what "in the back of my divs" means - I thought the [version 6](https://jsfiddle.net/54urb9zb/6/) above would be behind the divs

Comment: You got it man. You're awesome ... your help means a lot to me. :D

Comment: Hit Pete, After I move the code from JS Fiddle in my real situation. The blue line doesn't seem to stay in the back like your Fiddle. Here what it looks [like](http://jsfiddle.net/bheng/8p1t9hgt/). Any Ideas ?